# Cелектор jsoup. Проблема с корректным выводом информации

Tags: java, jsoup

Из вебкода

```
<div class="story__date" title="2 ноября 2016 в 23:58">7 дней назад</div>
```

мне нужно выделить "2 ноября 2016 в 23:58".

У меня есть конструкция

```
doc.select("div.story__date").attr("title")
```

с помощью которой я добавляю выбранную информацию в поле своего класса типа String, но когда вывожу ее на экран, то вместо

> 2 ноября 2016 в 23:58

выводится ерундна:

> 1478120321

проблема кодировки?

Comment: 1478120321 - это unix timestamp для 2016-11-02T20:58:41+00:00 или искомая дата по московскому времени. Вполне может быть, что на сайте есть скрипт, который делает преобразование с учетом часового пояса клиента. Тогда, поскольку jsoup не умеет в скрипты, то вы получаете дату, как она отдается с сервера. Можно сделать `Long.parseLong`, умножить на `1000L` и подставить в `new Date()` или чем там вы хотите дату обрабатывать.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы на счет скрипта

Comment: Эх, была такая версия, я пробовал перевести `1478120321` в дату вот [тут](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/), и оно показало `1970`-й год. Однако я забыл указать там галочку `milli` :)

Comment: @post_zeew, а есть возможность перевести ее в человеческий формат? Желательно без сторонних библиотек?

Comment: @РоманDriveMind, Да, можно. Вам же выше написали. Ну или с помощью `Calendar.setTimeInMillis(...)`.

Comment: @post_zeew, ваш метод однозначно удобнее

Comment: Если понадобится решение                                                                      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1478120321L * 1000L);
System.out.println("" + calendar.getTime());